# Doctrine not Inserting Datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, symfony1, doctrine

Doctrine ORM 1.0 inserts Datetime values in ISO8601 format; that is: '2009-10-23 12:31:22', but for some reason using SQL Server 2008 Express as my DB, throws an exception as if the value inserted was NULL. 
Here's the query:

`{sfDoctrineLogger} executeQuery : INSERT INTO [vbif_inventarios] ([anulado], [id_restaurante], [fecha_inventario]) VALUES (?, ?, ?) - (0, 1, 2009-10-29 06:06:00 )`

The column [fecha_inventario] is a DATETIME column.

Which gives me:

`[err] {Doctrine_Connection_Mssql_Exception} SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10007 No se puede insertar el valor NULL en la columna 'fecha_inventario', tabla 'vbif_operativo.dbo.vbif_inventarios'. La columna no admite valores NULL. Error de INSERT. [10007] (severity 5) [(null)]`

Trying to manually insert the same string in the datefield (A query through SQL Manager) column does not work either, is there a way i can make SQL Server to accept these Strings correctly? i've read that it does support them.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work either"?  By "SQL Manager" do you mean Management Studio, or Enterprise Manager, or Query Analyzer?  How are you inserting the string into the column?  Is this open table / edit top n rows, or something else?  OrbMan is correct, you can't just embed a date without quotes into a parameter statement like that, you need to wrap it in single quotes.  I am not familiar with Doctrine but if possible have you considered using stored procedures?

Comment: By that i meant, Running 

INSERT INTO [vbif_administracion].[dbo].[vbif_inventarios]([id_restaurante],[fecha_inventario],[anulado])
VALUES(1,'2009-10-29 10:25:00',0)GO

in SQL Management Studio, and yes OrbMan is right (thanks) but as i'm using doctrine, i'm not directly writing the statement, so it kinda looks like a doctrine issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the date string.

```
INSERT INTO [vbif_inventarios] ([anulado], [id_restaurante], [fecha_inventario]) VALUES (?, ?, ?) - (0, 1, '2009-10-29 06:06:00' )
```